# Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth476ff90: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, docker, docker-swarm, networkmanager, oraclelinux

I'm seeing this error message in my Docker Swarm manager:

```
 11278  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager systemd-udevd[3557149]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
 11279  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager systemd-udevd[3557149]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth7bdf732: No such file or directory
 11280  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1675674428.1388] manager: (veth7bdf732): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/36528)
 11281  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager systemd-udevd[3557148]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
 11282  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager systemd-udevd[3557148]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethe6bef2b: No such file or directory
 11283  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager kernel: veth1: renamed from veth7bdf732
 11284  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager kernel: br0: port 3(veth1) entered blocking state
 11285  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager kernel: br0: port 3(veth1) entered disabled state
 11286  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager kernel: device veth1 entered promiscuous mode
 11287  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager kernel: br0: port 3(veth1) entered blocking state
 11288  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager kernel: br0: port 3(veth1) entered forwarding state
 11289  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 3(veth17599e0) entered blocking state
 11290  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 3(veth17599e0) entered disabled state
 11291  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager kernel: device veth17599e0 entered promiscuous mode
 11292  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 3(veth17599e0) entered blocking state
 11293  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager kernel: docker_gwbridge: port 3(veth17599e0) entered forwarding state
 11294  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1675674428.1755] manager: (veth476ff90): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/36529)
 11295  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager systemd-udevd[3557161]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
 11296  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1675674428.1765] manager: (veth17599e0): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/36530)
 11297  Feb  6 10:07:08  swarm-manager systemd-udevd[3557161]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth476ff90: No such file or directory
```

I would like to know the real impact of it as all the services are running properly but at some point I noticed some instability in my system, generating in some way an OOM that may lead to a PostgreSQL database inconsistency.

I also looked at the same issue over Stackoverflow and github but none of them is approaching me to a solution.

My OS is Oracle Linux 8.6